# very simple android app crashes because View is null

Tags: android

I'm just learning to write apps for Android using Android Studio.  I'm following a tutorial to create a simple activity (MainActivity) that has a plain text and a button.  Entering some text and clicking the button should just start another activity (DisplayMessageActivity) that displays the text from MainActivity.  I'm typing everything exactly the way the tutorial says, but the app crashes at findViewByID because the View is null.  If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it.  Here are my .xml and .java files for the two activities; I've commented where it crashes.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void sendMessage(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText9);
        // IT CRASHES HERE BECAUSE v IS NULL
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText9" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText9"
        android:layout_width="143dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(message);
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="30dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: try this    String message = editText.getText().toString();


if (message  != null && !message.getText().toString().isEmpty() )
{   
message  = message.getText().toString();
}

Comment: First, you don't need a 2nd `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` because you already did that in `onCreate`. Next, you can't use `findViewById` on `v` because `v` is the View clicked (the button). You should `findViewById` on the main layout itself (where the EditText is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change MainActivity to this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void sendMessage(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EditText editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    // IT CRASHES HERE BECAUSE v IS NULL
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra("message", message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

> change DisplayMessageActivity to this.

```
    public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no crash fix. why this answer is accepted?

Answer (score 0):

try to put this code after  this line

```
String message = editText.getText().toString();


if (message  != null && !message.getText().toString().isEmpty() )
{   
message  = message.getText().toString();
}
```

or you can try to catch v

```
          public void sendmessage(View v) {

          String intent = textPhoneNo.getText().toString();
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          EditText editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText9);
          try {
            String message = editText.getText().toString();
            message message = message.getDefault();


          } catch (Exception v) {
            message.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Ops !! something went wrong",
                message.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

would it compile ?

Answer (score 0):

change `sendMessage` function:

```
public void sendMessage(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);

        //layout for activity was set at onCreate
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // you should find edittext in activity layout but you find in view v
        //EditText editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText9);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);

        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling

```
EditText editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText9);
```

instead of

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
```

When you click your button and that function is called, the `View` passed in is that of the button. Calling `findViewById` looks for a sub-view, which is in the parent activity not the button, so then `editText` is null.

Also, do not call `setContentView` in the `sendMessage` routine, you already call that in `onCreate`

Answer (score 0):

Change your send message to look as follows

```
 public void sendMessage(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

1. Removed the line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` as you have already done this in onCreate().

2.Changed `EditText editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText9);` to `EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);` as the edittext is present in activity_main.xml you need reference from there.